# App and Xcode crash when using stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to convert a path into a directory in order to upload it to the web with Dropbox. I need to remove the first part of this path. This is my code:

```
func camCaptureComplete(cam: DIYCam!, withAsset asset: NSDictionary!){
    println("completed")
    var path : String = asset["path"] as String;
    path = path.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")
}
```

Unfortunately both Xcode and my App crash when I run this code... I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What kind of error do you get when it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode6 is still beta software and doesn't need much of a reason to crash, so not much help you can get about it here.

However, you are getting a dictionary value through a subscript. This returns an Optional, as it is possible that the key-value does not exist. So you could try:

```
if var path: String = asset["path"] {
    path = path = path.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")
}
```